# canvas.drawWindow is not a function

Tags: firefox, canvas, image-capture

I am working on adding the contents of an iFrame to the canvas in order to save it as an image. I get the 'canvas.drawWindow is not a function' error in FF.

I understand that this only works with Chrome privileges - How do I enable chrome privileges or how should I avoid the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[drawWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29) is a method belonging to [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), not [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) (canvas) itself.  Per the docs, "To get [the context] object, call getContext() on a canvas, supplying "2d" as the argument"

example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawWindow(...);
```